# Update Panel AsyncPostBack and PostBack triggers

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a page in which much of the HTML is generated by client side script (JQuery). I added a server side ASP.NET File control to upload files to server.

Now files are getting uploaded on the button click, which causes POSTBACK and so all the textboxes Company Name, Street Name, City Client etc are lost, as they were generated by JQuery.

I put the upload portion in UpdatePanel and registered AsyncPostBack Trigger, but then I am not getting HttpContext object at code-behind. I turned Async to a full postback using PostBackTrigger then the things became the same as before(i.e. without an update panel).

Now I have two questions from you people:
- What is the use of an update panel if it behaves in the same way as the page without an update panel. (PostBackTrigger)
- What should I do with the above problem?

**CODE:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="uploadUpdatePanel" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <input id="fileField" type="file" runat="server" multiple="multiple" />
                    <asp:Button ID="uploadButton" runat="server" Text="Upload Documents" OnClick="uploadButton_Click" />
                 </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="uploadButton" />
                    <%--<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="uploadButton" />--%>
                </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: You must recreate the controls after the postback. If they where created dynamically in ASP.NET code behind, the answer would be the same: Dynamically created controls must be recreated with each postback.

Comment: It would really help to see some code here.

Look into using AsyncPostBackTriggers

Comment: @KidBilly Please see the update above.

Comment: @Alexander I am not creating controls from code behind, but rather through JQuery. I cannot recreate them. Secondly user also fill out some data in the boxes, how will I fill that, even if I create them?

Comment: Well you are mixing two worlds. If your controls would be created in codebehind, I could answer the question, very quickly; recreate on each postback, the ViewState helps to keep user input.

Comment: @Alexander Yes that is true. But I fear thats not the case, I am creating controls from JQuery, at client side.

Comment: Hence, you have to take care of saving the user input and the controls yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, FileUpload controls don't work in UpdatePanels.  I've run into this issue before and as far as I know, there's no way around it.  You're just going to have to accept a full PostBack and work on saving user inputs.

Comment: Yes after a lot of searching, I too have come to this conclusion. Can you suggest a way to upload files from client side? I have googled but cannot implement any solution. I am now implementing the client side upload using Jquery/Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I would respectfully disagree with CrazyPaste's declaration that the UploadFile control doesn't work inside an update panel. I spent hours on this problem and finally found the answer on an obscure five-year-old post on the asp.net forums.

Check to see if your .aspx `<form>` tag looks like this:

> `<form id="Form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server">`

If it is an unadorned tag like `<form id="Form1" runat="server">` that's probably your problem.

The majority of responses I found elsewhere mentioned setting the update triggers, as you have, and is correct, but setting the triggers is useless if your form tag is not correctly configured. Nowhere except on the 2007 forum page was this suggestion made. It works great now.

I hope this helps!